# (ask) XOR calculation issue on file in java

Tags: java, xor, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, parity

I would like to execute XOR operation in my code. However I have strange behavior on the output. Sometimes the result is right but sometime it's not.
Here's the situation:
I have file which I already split into two parts and then I created one parity file using xor operation on both file (source files). So now I have three files. Then I deleted one of the source file. I would like to retrieve the missing file within xor operation between parity file and the remaining source file regarding the missing file. I am using hash function to check whether the output is correct or not. If the function is called only one time, everything is fine, but whenever I have many operations to retrieve the missing file on other files, sometimes my function generates the wrong result.
When they generate the wrong results, it's always generating the same file. BUT if I put thread.sleep for 1 second, they always generate the correct result even if I have more than 1000 operations.

Could somebody help me to spot which part of my code is broke?

```
private byte[] parityByte(byte[] firstByte, byte[] secondByte) {
    int size1;
    size1 = firstByte.length;

    int size2; 
    size2 = secondByte.length;

    byte[] parity;
    parity = new byte[size1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        parity[i] = (byte) (firstByte[i] ^ secondByte[i]);
    }
    for (int i = size2; i < size1; i++) {
        parity[i] = firstByte[i];
    }
    return parity;
}

/**
 * get original chunks
 */
public Chunk getOriginal(Chunk parity, Chunk compare, String orig) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    File par = new File(parity.getHash());

    InputStream parity = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(parity.getHash()));

    InputStream source = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(compare.getHash()));

    int size = (int) par.length();

    int bufferSize = size;
    byte[] firstBuffer = new byte[size];
    byte[] secondBuffer = new byte[size];

    long remainSize;
    byte[] destByte = new byte[1];
    parity.read(destByte, 0, 1);
    Integer dest = new Integer(destByte[0]);
    remainSize = size - 1 - dest;

    OutputStream originalChunk;
    originalChunk = new FileOutputStream(orig);

    while (remainSize > 0) {
        if (remainSize > bufferSize) {
            remainSize -= bufferSize;
        } else {
            bufferSize = (int) remainSize;
            firstBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            secondBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            remainSize = 0;
        }
        parity.read(firstBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        source.read(secondBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        originalChunk.write(parityByte(firstBuffer, secondBuffer));

    }
    originalChunk.flush();
    parity.close();
    source.close();
    originalChunk.close();

    Chunk tempChunk = Chunk.newChunk(orig);
    return tempChunk;
}
```

Thank you
sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that all the reads fill the buffer. Check the Javadoc. The read(byte[] ...) method returns a value, and it is for a reason.

Have a look at DataInputStream.readFully() for a simple solution.

Comment: Thanks @ejp but using DataInputStream.readFully() still doesnt work.